# MenuItem's sub menu don't open

Tags: c#, wpf, menuitem

I have a `MenuItem` with sub-buttons in a `ToolBar`:

```
<ToolBar x:Name="toolBar" VerticalAlignment="Top">
      <Button x:Name="btnNew" Content="New"/>
      <MenuItem x:Name="miWindow" Header="Add windows">
             <Button x:Name="btnScore1" Content="Score"/>
             <Button x:Name="btnScore2" Content="Score (complete)"/>
      </MenuItem>
 </ToolBar>
```

When I click on it, my sub-menu don't open. Did I forget something ?

Also, I tried to handle the click event of the `MenuItem`, but it's never fired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be inside a `Menu` Tag:

```
<ToolBar x:Name="toolBar" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Button x:Name="btnNew" Content="New"/>
    <Menu>
        <MenuItem x:Name="miWindow" Header="Add windows">
            <Button x:Name="btnScore1" Content="Score"/>
            <Button x:Name="btnScore2" Content="Score (complete)"/>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
</ToolBar>
```

Comment: Thanks ! I only spent one day for this ... *sigh*